# How to make scrapy follwing links and scrape them

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm very new with Scrapy and Python and want to learn it. For my first project, I wanted to create a spider, which crawls all sites of [www.norisbank.de](http://www.norisbank.de) and **scrapes** items from them to arrange it url by url in a csv file. So far, so good; I managed it perfectly :-) for the startpage, however I wasn't able to convince scrapy to follow the urls on the start page and **scrape** them, too (at least, the xpath selector gives me the urls found on the start page). I'm pretty sure, that my code is terrible however first steps are always diffcult. :-) Anyone able to help me to do better?

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

```
name = "nbtest"

allowed_domains = ['norisbank.de']

start_urls = ['https://www.norisbank.de']



custom_settings={ 'FEED_URI': "norisbank_%(time)s.csv",

                  'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',

                  'DEPTH_LIMIT': 3}



def parse(self, response):

    page = response.url.split("/")[-2]

    filename = 'nbtest-%s.html' % page

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:

        f.write(response.body)

    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)



    #Content Extraction

    print(response.url)

    siteurl = response.xpath("//link[@rel='canonical']/@href")[0].getall()

    dbCategory = response.xpath("//meta[@name='dbCategory']/@content")[0].getall()

    titles = response.css('title::text').extract()

    descriptions = response.xpath("//meta[@name='description']/@content")[0].getall()

    date = response.xpath("//meta[@name='date']/@content")[0].getall()

    version = response.xpath("//meta[@name='v']/@content")[0].getall()

    time = response.xpath("//meta[@name='time']/@content")[0].getall()



    #Sort extracted conten in rows

    for item in zip(siteurl,dbCategory,titles,descriptions,date,version,time):

        scraped_info = {

           'siteurl' : item[0],

            'dbCategory' : item [1],

            'title' : item [2],

            'description' : item [3],

            'date' : item [4],

            'version' : item [5],

            'time' : item [6],

        }



        yield scraped_info



    next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "norisbank")]/@href').get()

    if next_page is not None:

        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)

        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: set the last line to `yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)`

Comment: Sorry, does not work. scrapy still exits after the start page.

Comment: Now I have changed the "norisbank" keyword in the xpath selector to "html" and I get a second page scrapped; the first html page referred to on the start page. However, after that the spider exits and is not going further down the start page. So I now have two entries in my csv.... the start page and the first html refferd to. I have no idea, why scrapy does not go further....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start off by stating that what you are trying to achieve is suited for `crawl spider`, not the regular spider. You can specify your selector in the parameter [restrict_xpaths](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor).

If you want to use `scrapy.Spider` for this scenario, you would have to find all links and `yield` a `Request` for all of them at once.

```
all_pages = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "norisbank")]/@href').getall()
for next_pagein all_pages :
    next_page= response.urljoin(next_page)
    yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

The most important concept to understand here is that when you yield a `Request`, you are just sending requests to the scrapy engine. These are **not** being executed immediately. These requests are being sent to a pool from where scrapy engine will pick them up and process. You can read about architecture of scrapy [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html).

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! This has heped a lot - not just to get one tep further and being able to scrap the sites, but also in understanding the mechanism of scrapy a lot better! Thank you again, really pperciate your help!

Comment: Glad that it helped. Please mark this answer as Accepted